# Delete only the first row of dataframe that satisfies a condition

Tags: r, conditional-statements, delete-row

I want to delete only one of the dataframe rows base on one condition.

But Existing codes will delete all of rows which be contained this condition. But I want to delete only the first row that satisfies the condition.

How can I do this?

Comment: You need to be much more specific. This is the typical kind of question that gets quickly closed. Give an example of a condition, please. And of a dataframe. In the mean time, consider `which(condition)[1]` as an index to your df.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example how to remove the first instance of a matching element:

```
> df <- data.frame(x=rep(1:3,3))
> df[,'x']
[1] 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3
> df[which(df$x==2)[1],'x']
[1] 2
> df[-which(df$x==2)[1],'x']
[1] 1 3 1 2 3 1 2 3
```

Comment: `-which(z)` is unsafe. If the condition is never met, you'll get an empty table, or with `-which(z)[1]`, you'll get a one-row table of NAs.